# Unable to set a boolean flag from scheduled executor service

Tags: java, boolean, scheduledexecutorservice

I need to run a piece of code periodically. This code checks a condition and sets a boolean flag.
In order to run it periodically, I am using `scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate` method.

The scheduler works fine, but it is unable to set the flag.
The flag value is always false.

Please advise.

```
package healthCheck;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test {
    private static ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        Future<?> scheduledFuture = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new SomeFiveSecondelyJob(),  1, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Flag at scheduler"+scheduledFuture.get());
    }

    public static void contextDestroyed() {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }

}
```

The Runnable code:

```
package healthCheck;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class SomeFiveSecondelyJob implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://www.google.co.in/");
            HttpsURLConnection connection = 
                (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);

            int code = connection.getResponseCode();

            if (code / 100 == 2) {
                ItSystemFlag.setFlag(true);
                System.out.println("System is up");

            } else {
                ItSystemFlag.setFlag(false);
                System.out.println("System unavailable: " + code);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ItSystemFlag.setFlag(false);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(ItSystemFlag.getFlag());

    }

}
```

I am using a static volatile variable as a flag:

```
package healthCheck;

public class ItSystemFlag {
    private static volatile Boolean flag = false;

    public static void setFlag(Boolean flag) {
        ItSystemFlag.flag = flag;
        System.out.println("seting the flag to :" + ItSystemFlag.flag);
    }
    public static Boolean getFlag() {
        return ItSystemFlag.flag;
    }
}
```

Second client class:

```
package healthCheck;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
            System.out.println("From client "+ItSystemFlag.getFlag());
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: A flag you set in the memory of one JVM can't possibly be visible in the memory of another JVM. If you want to communicate between two different processes (JVM), you'll have to use files, or sockets for example. Not in-memory flags.

Answer (score 1):

These are two different java processes. The global variable is not shared between them. Try:

```
public class Test {
  private static ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

  public static void main(String[] args) 
          throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
      scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
      Future<?> scheduledFuture = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
          new SomeFiveSecondelyJob(),  1, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      System.out.println("Flag at scheduler"+scheduledFuture.get());

      for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
          System.out.println("From client "+ItSystemFlag.getFlag());
          Thread.sleep(6000);
      }
  }

  public static void contextDestroyed() {
      scheduler.shutdownNow();
  }


}
```

First run the scheduler and then in the same java process check the global flag.

Comment: Thanks, It is working when used in same jvm process.